# Android - Custom ListView with Spinner loses its value

Tags: android, listview, view, spinner

I have a custom ListView with an image, two TextViews and a Spinner. My problem is that the Spinner loses its value when I scroll on ListView. How could keep Spinner value in each cell?

below is code part of my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View vi = contentView;
    item = items.get(position);

    if (vi == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_products, null);


        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgCellProducts);

        holder.tvTextCellProducts =  (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvTextCellProducts);
        holder.tvPreciosProducts = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvPreciosProductos);
        holder.spCellProducts = (Spinner)  vi.findViewById(R.id.spCellProducts);


        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();  
    }       


    holder.spCellProducts.setTag(position);
    switch (item.getPossibleSize()) {
    case 0:
        holder.spCellProducts.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    case 1:
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                R.array.sizeSmallMedium, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //holder.spCellProducts.setDescendantFocusability(parent.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
        holder.spCellProducts.setAdapter(adapter);

        break;

    case 2:
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                R.array.sizeSmallMediumBig, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.spCellProducts.setAdapter(adapter2);

        break;

    }
    holder.spCellProducts.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    if (position == ((Integer) holder.spCellProducts.getTag())) {
        holder.spCellProducts.setSelection(item.getSize());

    }
    holder.tvTextCellProducts.setText(item.getName());
    holder.tvPreciosProducts.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    switch (item.getIcon()) {
    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(vi.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame));
        break;
    case 2:
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(vi.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_dropdown));
    }

    return vi;
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long arg3) {

    items.get(((Integer) parent.getTag())).setSize(position);
    ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.azul_oscuro));

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
```

EDIT: SOLVED

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should get the index from your adapter: `setSelection(adapter.getPosition(item.getSize()));`

Comment: my problem was not assigned a tag to each spinner. Now he's helping me id I assign one to each element in my data list. And that differentiate each Spinner.